# Jquery slidery with Next/Previous buttons doesn't work correctly

Tags: jquery, slider

I work on a slider but the previous and the next button doesn't work. 
Can somebody telle me whats wrong on my code?

The size of the code is to much, please check the jsFiddle link

```
www.jsfiddle.net/joppieb/xjfvmtsw/1/
```

hope somebody can help me :)

Greetz Jop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the button listeners inside the `document ready` and changed them to call the function `showSlide(newSlide)`. That worked.

```
$('#prev').click(function(){
    newSlide = sliderInt - 1;
    showSlide(newSlide);
    return false;
});


$('#next').click(function(){
    newSlide = sliderInt + 1;
    showSlide(newSlide);
    return false;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the correct answer. Ik have changed the code. 
I tested the buttons and there is another problem.

The button next work correctly but the previous button not. 
If i click on the button prev it goes well until the last item.
The slider does show a blank item and he doesn't start the loop again

the link : www.jsfiddle.net/joppieb/xjfvmtsw/2/